# Failed to install Realm C++ SDK

Tags: c++, installation, cmake, realm, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install realm cpp sdk on ubuntu 20.04 (gcc, g++ version 9.4.0) using `cmake`, following the [documentations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/cpp/install/#install)

I got the `GIT_TAG` from the top of the [page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/cpp/latest/) next to the SDK name and use it on my `CMakeList.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(MyRealmCppProject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
Include(FetchContent)
set(REALM_USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL ON)
FetchContent_Declare(
  cpprealm
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/realm/realm-cpp.git
  GIT_TAG        5dab867db1e3ed63b1c4aba611991724d16cd0ce
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cpprealm)
add_executable(myApp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myApp PRIVATE cpprealm)
```

It seems like the `cmake` runs fine, but the last step `make` results in error.

```
...
Scanning dependencies of target cpprealm_exe_tests
[ 90%] Building CXX object _deps/cpprealm-build/CMakeFiles/cpprealm_exe_tests.dir/tests/str_tests.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object _deps/cpprealm-build/CMakeFiles/cpprealm_exe_tests.dir/tests/list_tests.cpp.o
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp: In lambda function:
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp:331:19: error: use of deleted function ‘realm::notification_token::notification_token(const realm::notification_token&)’
  331 |            return token;
      |                   ^~~~~
In file included from /home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/src/cpprealm/object.hpp:22,
                 from /home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/src/cpprealm/persisted_embedded.hpp:22,
                 from /home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/src/cpprealm/sdk.hpp:29,
                 from /home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/main.hpp:5,
                 from /home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp:1:
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/src/cpprealm/notifications.hpp:39:8: note: ‘realm::notification_token::notification_token(const realm::notification_token&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘realm::notification_token’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
   39 | struct notification_token {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp: In lambda function:
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp:371:19: error: use of deleted function ‘realm::notification_token::notification_token(const realm::notification_token&)’
  371 |            return token;
      |                   ^~~~~
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp: In lambda function:
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp:402:19: error: use of deleted function ‘realm::notification_token::notification_token(const realm::notification_token&)’
  402 |            return token;
      |                   ^~~~~
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp: In function ‘void CATCH2_INTERNAL_TEST_0()’:
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp:445:37: error: cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘const std::variant<std::monostate, long int, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >, realm::uuid, realm::object_id>&’
  445 |        obj.list_mixed_col.push_back(42);
      |                                     ^~
      |                                     |
      |                                     int
In file included from /home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/src/cpprealm/sdk.hpp:32,
                 from /home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/main.hpp:5,
                 from /home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/tests/list_tests.cpp:1:
/home/malacoda/am_offline_db/cloud_db_test/build/_deps/cpprealm-src/src/cpprealm/persisted_list.hpp:171:33: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void realm::persisted<std::vector<Duration>, typename std::enable_if<std::negation<std::disjunction<std::is_same<typename realm::internal::type_info::type_info<ValueType, void>::internal_type, std::optional<realm::internal::bridge::obj_key> >, std::is_same<typename realm::internal::type_info::type_info<ValueType, void>::internal_type, realm::internal::bridge::obj_key>, std::is_same<typename realm::internal::type_info::type_info<ValueType, void>::internal_type, realm::internal::bridge::list>, std::is_same<typename realm::internal::type_info::type_info<ValueType, void>::internal_type, realm::internal::bridge::dictionary> > >::value, void>::type>::push_back(const T&) [with T = std::variant<std::monostate, long int, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >, realm::uuid, realm::object_id>; typename std::enable_if<std::negation<std::disjunction<std::is_same<typename realm::internal::type_info::type_info<ValueType, void>::internal_type, std::optional<realm::internal::bridge::obj_key> >, std::is_same<typename realm::internal::type_info::type_info<ValueType, void>::internal_type, realm::internal::bridge::obj_key>, std::is_same<typename realm::internal::type_info::type_info<ValueType, void>::internal_type, realm::internal::bridge::list>, std::is_same<typename realm::internal::type_info::type_info<ValueType, void>::internal_type, realm::internal::bridge::dictionary> > >::value, void>::type = void]’
  171 |         void push_back(const T& value)
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
make[2]: *** [_deps/cpprealm-build/CMakeFiles/cpprealm_exe_tests.dir/build.make:76: _deps/cpprealm-build/CMakeFiles/cpprealm_exe_tests.dir/tests/list_tests.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:374: _deps/cpprealm-build/CMakeFiles/cpprealm_exe_tests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I think the problem might be from the sdk itself, but I am not sure.
What should I do to install and build Realm C++ SDK successfully?

Comment: I don't think you need its tests. Try `set(REALM_NO_TESTS ON)`

Comment: I removed everything except the `CMakeList.txt`, and tried adding `set(REALM_NO_TESTS ON)` after the `set(REALM_USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL ON)`, but the same error occured.

Comment: you'd need to do `set(REALM_NO_TESTS ON)` before calling `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cpprealm)`. You should also probably report this issue to the maintainers. It might be that whatever compiler they are running this kind of test with just doesn't raise this error and converts the `int` to a `long int`. nvm I see you already did: https://github.com/realm/realm-cpp/issues/74

Comment: Did you try `GIT_TAG        v0.1.1-alpha`?

Comment: @Jay Yes, but the exact same error occured

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I got from the [github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cpp/issues/74) I made, it is said that anything lower than GCC 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 is not tested yet. Since I am using GCC 9.4.0 and Ubuntu 20.04, there might be compatibility issue (I think what starball says is right). Preventing the SDK from performing test by using `cmake -DREALM_CPP_NO_TESTS=1 ..` should let it build successfully.

Below codes run successfully after the build.

```
#include <cpprealm/sdk.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "hello realm" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Since I manage to build the SDK successfully this way, I consider this question as answered.

However, I am still a little concerned because skipping test might not solve its underlying issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of the SDK, it isn't tested with anything lower than GCC 11 and Ubuntu 22.04. You could try to set `REALM_CPP_NO_TESTS` to a truth value. Ex. passing `-DREALM_CPP_NO_TESTS=1` to the CMake configure command.

For more recent versions of the SDK, apparently it supports GCC 8.3 and above.

See also [this issue ticket](https://github.com/realm/realm-cpp/issues/74) which the asker of this question raised.